# What would be the best practice to perform actions on document that have list of docs that have list of docs?

Tags: mongodb

I have a user document that looks like this:

```
{
  "userId": "249869823570",
  "name": "john",
  "country": "usa",
  "active": true,
  "serviceProviders": [
    {
      "serviceProvidersId": "897892893",
      "serviceProvidersName": "AT&T",
      "active": true,
      "serviceProviderContactPerson": []
    },
    {
      "serviceProvidersId": "82589628569",
      "serviceProvidersName": "T-Mobile",
      "active": true,
      "serviceProviderContactPerson": []
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to create 3 methods to insert/update/delete a serviceProviderContactPerson. my dilema is, my main document have array of serviceProviders, and a serviceProvider have a list of serviceProviderContactPerson...what would be the best practice in mongo to work this?

serviceProviderContactPerson document will look like this:

```
{
    "contactId": "873498798",
    "name": "Mark",
    "email": "mark@tmobile.com",
    "phone": "917-475-4637"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use update to perform all operations in 3.6.

Insert a new array element where serviceProvidersId = "897892893"

```
db.colname.update(
  {"serviceProviders.serviceProvidersId":"897892893"},
  {$push: {"serviceProviders.$.serviceProviderContactPerson":serviceProviderContactPersonDoc}}
)
```

Update phone where serviceProvidersId = "897892893" and contactId = "873498798"

```
db.colname.update(
  {},
  {$set: {"serviceProviders.$[sp].serviceProviderContactPerson.$[spc].phone":phone value}},
  {arrayFilters:[{"sp.serviceProvidersId":"897892893"}, {"spc.contactId":"873498798"}]}
)
```

Delete array element where serviceProvidersId = "897892893" and contactId = "873498798"

```
db.colname.update(
      {},
      {$pull: {"serviceProviders.$[sp].serviceProviderContactPerson":{"contactId":"873498798"}}},
      {arrayFilters:[{"sp.serviceProvidersId":"897892893"}]}
    )
```

Comment: I was trying to do findAndModify with something like this: ```val query = json("userId"-> "249869823570", "serviceProviders. serviceProvidersId" -> "897892893", "serviceProviders. serviceProvidersId.contactId" -> "873498798")
    val update = json("$set" -> json("serviceProviders.$. serviceProviderContactPerson.$" -> contact))```

Comment: Multiple positional operators are not allowed in versions below 3.6.

Comment: so how can i accomplish this using findAndModify? cause this is how I worked so far

Comment: what is your version ?

Comment: 3.4, cant upgrade

Comment: Unfortunately its not straightforward in 3.4 version. You will need to redesign your structure so you dont have nested arrays at more than one level. Try moving the contact array to the top as well. Something like `"serviceProviders": [
    {
      "serviceProvidersId": "897892893",
      "serviceProvidersName": "AT&T",
      "active": true
    } ...
  ],
 "serviceProviderContactPerson": [{"serviceProvidersId": "897892893","contactId": "873498798",
    "name": "Mark",
    "email": "mark@tmobile.com",
    "phone": "917-475-4637"}, ....]`

Comment: i guess that is a good idea...working with two levels arrays is a pain in the a** :/ thanks buddy